# Does Kotlin's "@Parcelize" work with non data classes?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have simple data classes. I mean, they are data classes logically, but not `data class`, because I need inheritance and other constructors. They only have fields (of basic types `Int?`, `String?`, or `List<String>?`, etc), and constructors.

I need to pass them (all of their fields need to be passed) from Activity to Activity, so I need to make them parcellisable (or is there a better way?). I first created them as `data class` and just added `@Parcelize`. Even though there was a warning and red line that said "CREATOR" or something, I could ignore them and the app worked as intended.

But, now for the reasons above, I changed them to normal classes, and suddenly there is a compilation error.

```
Error:java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.parcel.ParcelableCodegenExtension.getPropertiesToSerialize(ParcelableCodegenExtension.kt:374)
    ....too long...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

How can I solve this problem? Should I use `data class`? But I need to parse a JSON object to create them. The classes look like these (not actual classes, but simplified for illustration purposes). Is there a better way than implementing that boring, bulky parcellable code by hand?

```
@Parcelize
open class Dog():Parcelable
{
    var someField1;
    var someField2;
    constructor(data:JSON):this()
    {
       //parse data to set the fields.
    }
}

@Parcelize
class Doge:Dog
{
    var someField3;
    var someField4;

    constructor():super(); //I do not use it, but for parcellable
    constructor(data:JSON):super(data)
    {
       //parse data to set the fields.
    }
}
```

---

PS. I had to switch to PaperParcel. It was very similar to Kotlin's, but it did not require a primary constructor. It only required the same thing to be any constructor, so I could just create a secondary constructor with the same argument names as those of fields, and it worked. Although, I wonder why the CREATOR could not be created automatically.

For example,

```
@PaperParcel
class Doge:Dog
{
    var someField3;
    var someField4;

    //Needed only for PaperParcel
    constructor(someField3, someField4)
    {
       this.someField3 = someField3;
       this.someField4 = someField4;
    }
    companion object
    {
        @JvmField val CREATOR = PaperParcelDoge.CREATOR
    }
    //end of PaperParcel stuff.

    constructor(data:JSON):super(data)
    {
       //parse data to set the fields.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/), your properties should be declared inside your primary constructor.

> **Parcelable support**
>
> Android Extensions plugin now includes an automatic
> Parcelable implementation generator. Declare the serialized properties
> in a primary constructor and add a @Parcelize annotation, and
> writeToParcel()/createFromParcel() methods will be created
> automatically:
>
> ```
> @Parcelize
> class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : Parcelable
> ```

Comment: So, in this case, the best way is to create a constructor like this`constructor(data:JSON):this(null,...,null){//parse json}`?

Comment: yes, but if too many of your parent properties have to be set at `null`, inheritance might not be the good choice

Comment: Thank you. It is like the parent class has 10+ fields and the child class has 2 fields. At first I tried not to use inheritance but just included the parent as a member of the child class, but that just did not look good to use. I mean, it would be `doge.dog.field1` instead of `doge.field1`. Or course creating a bridge field (I do not know the correct term, but I mean a property simply get/sets another class' property) for each parent property in the child did not look good either.

Comment: There is a problem. The child's parsing constructor originally called ':super(data)', but after this change it needs to call the primary constructor, instead. How can I call the parent's parsing constructor? It seems 'super(data)' inside the constructor does not work.

Comment: @DamnVegetables you should open another question regarding this new issue

Comment: @Benjamin can you provide a sample code for this scenario